# (Dice), population mean and variance of the odd numbers.

Tags: probability, expectation, dice, variance

> A fair die is rolled 100 times. Find the population mean and variance of the sum of the odd numbers that appear.

I am aware that the expected value for discrete multinomial distributions is $\Sigma \Sigma ... g(x_1 , x_2,...)f(x_1 ,x_2...)$. In this case, to find the expected value of the sum of the odd numbers that were rolled, should I not simply find the sum of the expected values for each of the individual odd numbers?

Couldn't something similar be done for variance? Or must I compute it using something like $Y= X_1 + 3X_3 +5X_5$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the mean, we find:

$$E[100X] = 100 E[X] = 100 \bigg(\frac{1}{6} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{6} \cdot 3 + \frac{1}{6} \cdot 5 + \frac{3}{6} \cdot 0\bigg) = 100 \cdot \frac{3}{2} = 150$$

For the variance, we find:

$$Var[100X] = 100 Var[X] = 100 \cdot \frac{\big(1-\frac{3}{2}\big)^2 + \big(3-\frac{3}{2}\big)^2 + \big(5-\frac{3}{2}\big)^2 + 3 \big(0-\frac{3}{2}\big)^2}{6}$$
$$= 100 \cdot \frac{0.5^2 + 1.5^2 + 3.5^2 + 3 \cdot 1.5^2}{6} = 100 \cdot  \frac{43}{12} \approx 358$$

Comment: Wow, thank you, this is a great example. But I'm a little confused, as I did have a good bit of your work for the expected value, yet I'm not sure of the purpose of the $ \frac{3}{6} \cdot 0 $ within the parenthesis of the expected value portion. Would you mind elaborating? I understand that you need to have the probabilities of 1,3,5 and thus arrive at the sum, but that last entry I'm unsure of.

Comment: @user455681 The probability of hitting an even number equals $\frac{3}{6}$, and in this case the value of the die does not contribute to the sum.

Comment: of course, perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to think about the variance:

Because we know the rolls are independent,

$$Var(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{100}x_i)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{100}Var(x_i)$$

We can then look at just $Var(x_i)$

$$Var(x_i) = E(x_i^2) - E(x_i)^2$$

$$E(x_i^2) = \frac{1}{6}*1^2 + \frac{1}{6}*3^2 + \frac{1}{6}*5^2 = \frac{35}{6}$$

$$Var(x_i)=\frac{35}{6}-(\frac{3}{2})^2=\frac{43}{12}$$

and then just plug back into the intitial equation

$$Var(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{100}x_i)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{100}\frac{43}{12}=100*\frac{43}{12}$$

Comment: Very true and a neat result. Yet, I'm curious, though I know that the expected value of the product of variables is equal to the product of the expected result of the variables, does this equality hold true for variance as well? While this would involve a longer proof than the simpler expected value result would yield, the book that I study does not mention any possibility of this.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand your question. For the result above, we don't need to use the variance of a product. We formulate variance in terms of expected values and solve from there. In the general sense, if $a$ and $b$ are independent, $Var(ab)=Var(a)Var(b)+Var(a)E^2(a)+Var(b)E^2(a)$, so the variance of the product does not equal the product of variances. You can find the proof for that derivation here: http://www.odelama.com/data-analysis/Commonly-Used-Math-Formulas/